# How to make a number type location to x,y type location?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to be more efficient when I want to check if a location is inside a "mini border". I was checking each possible location in the border and compared it to the actual location.

For example, when I wanted to check if a location is indie a rectangle,
I was providing the top left location, width and length of it. Then, comparing pixel location after pixel location to the actual location.

```
PROC CHECK_IF_IN_BORDER
;THIS PROC IS CHECKING IF THE LOCATION IS INSITE AN RECTANGLE THAT ITS 
;TOP LEFT CORNER IOS TOP_LEFT LOCATION OF BORDER AND ITS LENGTH 
;AND WIDTH ARE SIMILAR TO WHAT YOU RECIVE FROM THE USER

;----------------GET-------------------;
;BP + 4 - TOP LEFT LOCATION OF BORDER  ;
;BP + 6 - LENGTH               ;    
;BP + 8 - WIDTH                ;    
;BP + 10 - LOCATION            ;    
;--------------------------------------;

;------------RETURN--------------------;
; 1 - IF LOCATION IS IN BORDER         ;
; 0 - IF LOCATION IS NOT IN BORDER     ;
;--------------------------------------;
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP,SP
    PUSH AX
    PUSH DX
    PUSH BX
    
    MOV BX, 0 
    MOV AX,[BP+10]
    CHECK_NEXT_LINE1:   
        MOV DX,0 
        CHECK_LINE1:
            CMP AX,[BP+4]
            JE IN_BORDER1
            INC AX
            INC DX
        CMP DX,[BP+8] ;LENGTH
        JNE CHECK_LINE1
        ;----------------
        SUB AX,[BP+8] ;LENGTH
        ADD AX,320
        ;----------------
        INC BX
    CMP BX, [BP+6] ;WIDTH
    JNE CHECK_NEXT_LINE1
    ;NOT IN_BORDER:
        MOV [BP+10], 0 
        JMP SOF_BORDERPROC1
    IN_BORDER1:
        MOV [BP+10], 1 
    SOF_BORDERPROC1:
    POP BX
    POP DX
    POP AX
    POP BP
    RET 6 
ENDP CHECK_IF_IN_BORDER
```

Comment: Can't you just check if the pixel coordinates are within the range of the rectangle coordinates? Your rectangle would have coordinates (Left, Top) and (Right, Bottom). Check (x, y) as x >= Left and x <= Right, and y >= Top and y <= Bottom. Right is Left + width, and Bottom is Top + height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First let's be accurate

What you named *LENGTH* is actually *WIDTH* because it refers to the horizontal direction.
What you named *WIDTH* is actually *HEIGHT* because it refers to the vertical direction.

This remains true even if the width is much longer than the height and where it becomes tempting to speak about lengths and widths.

Also note that this same confusion has introduced a numerical error in your code (`[bp+6]` vs `[bp+8]`).

#### Then solve the issue

> How to make a number type location to x,y type location

Currently your program uses an (offset) address to refer to a pixel. It is easy to convert this address into the (x,y) coordinates. All it takes is a division by the length of the screen scanline. The quotient (`AX`) gives you the y-coordinate, the remainder (`DX`) gives you the x-coordinate.

```
mov     ax, [bp+10]  ; LOCATION
xor     dx, dx
mov     cx, 320
div     cx           ; -> DX = X, AX = Y
mov     si, dx       ; X
mov     di, ax       ; Y

mov     ax, [bp+4]  ; TOP LEFT LOCATION OF BORDER
xor     dx, dx
div     cx           ; -> DX = TopLeftX, AX = TopLeftY
```

The coordinates for the bottom right corner of your rectangle are

(BottomRightX, BottomRightY) = (TopLeftX + Width - 1, TopLeftY + Height - 1)

```
mov     bx, dx       ; TopLeftX
add     bx, [bp+6]   ; + WIDTH
dec     bx           ; - 1
mov     cx, ax       ; TopLeftY
add     cx, [bp+8]   ; + HEIGHT
dec     cx           ; - 1
```

This is what we have by now:

```
   <---------------WIDTH-------------->
(DX,AX) UpperLeft       
   *...................................                              ^
   .............................o......     o is (SI,DI) TestPixel   |
   ....................................                            HEIGHT
   ....................................                              |
   ...................................*                              v
                                   (BX,CX) BottomRight
```

The pixel falls within the rectangle if

`DX <= SI <= BX` and `AX <= DI <= CX`

which translates in assembly to:

```
    mov     word [bp+10], 0   ; LOCATION IS NOT IN BORDER
    cmp     dx, si
    ja      Outside
    cmp     si, bx
    ja      Outside
    cmp     ax, di
    ja      Outside
    cmp     di, cx
    ja      Outside
    inc     word [bp+10]      ; LOCATION IS IN BORDER
Outside:
    ; all the pops that you need ...
    ret     6
```